# Ajuda para análise sintática e morfológica de uma frase: "Tem mais depois da publicidade"

Tags: sintaxe, morfologia

Alguém poderia me dizer se as seguintes análises sintática e morfológica desta frase estão corretas?

"Tem mais depois da publicidade"

**Análise morfológica:**
TEM -> Verbo impessoal;
MAIS -> Advérbio (?);
DEPOIS DE -> Preposição;
A -> Artigo;
PUBLICIDADE -> Substantivo;

**Análise sintática:** Período simples. Sujeito inexistente (verbo impessoal); "Mais": Objeto direto; "Depois da publicidade": Adjunto adverbial

Comment: **(?)** Sujeito Indeterminado; **tem** (VTD); (Deveria ter um objeto direto aqui — mesmo que implícito); **mais** (Adj. Adv. Intensidade); **depois da publicidade** (Adj. Adv. de lugar).

Comment: **Tem** (Verbo Transitivo Direto); **Mais** (Advérbio de Intensidade); **depois da** (Locução prepositiva) + artigo feminino singular; **publicidade** (Substantivo).